# ADT Eclipse: Failed to Create The Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have the Installed Android ADT Bundle Installed. Ran Perfectly early today and now I have clicked on the desktop Icon and receive this:

"Failed to Create the Java Virtual Machine"

does anyone know how to get around this or had this problem before ?

Comment: Yes JDK is installed with the bundle.

Comment: I just shutdown my PC and tried again and it works again. Though now I am wondering why ?

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting the .ini in the folder, it worked for me at least!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open folder with Eclipse.exe and find eclipse.ini file
2. Replace -vmargs

by your current real path of javaw.exe:
-vm “c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\javaw.exe”

[image: vm args in eclipse ini]